# Specifying a website to appear in certain search engines and not others?

Tags: seo, search-engines

If you want a website to appear in DuckDuckGo for example and not Google, is this possible? Can you specify which search engines for a website appear in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can block Google and other search engines by using a [**robots.txt**](http://www.robotstxt.org/) file and [**meta name no index**](http://noarchive.net/meta/). You can use one or the other but Google recommends that you use both robots and meta.

To block a specific bot you use something like this within the robots.txt file:

```
User-agent: bot-name
Disallow: /
```

To block a specific bot using HTML then include this meta name within the `<head></head>`

```
<meta name="bot-name" content="noindex, nofollow">
```

*You can find the user agents listed on [**Google's Webmaster Help**](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl=en), below you can find all types of bot user agents that Google uses. Note that Adsbot, and Media partners may not crawl your site nor index.*

- Googlebot
- Googlebot-News
- Googlebot-Image
- Googlebot-Video
- Googlebot-Mobile
- Mediapartners-Google
- Mediapartners
- AdsBot-Google

*You can also find [**Microsoft's Bing crawler user agents**](http://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/which-crawlers-does-bing-use-8c184ec0) on their website*

- Bingbot
- Adidxbot
- MSNBot
- BingPreview

*DuckDuckGo bot uses the user agent `duckduckbot` and [**even lists the ip addresses**](https://duckduckgo.com/duckduckbot) it uses.*

- duckduckbot

*You can pretty much find any user agent using any good search engine, but to save your time its useful to [**bookmark this website**](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Crawlerlist/) that lists the majority of crawler user agents.*

*You can block all search engines by using `noindex` or `user-agent:*` i.e*

*Robots.txt*

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

*Meta Name*

```
`<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
```